# Python - How to get a list of background images used by a camera?

Tags: python, camera, image

I am trying to use python to get a list of names of background images that are being used by a certain camera, I've tried to do it like this:

```
print(bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].background_images)
```

which gives me:

```
<bpy_collection[1], CameraBackgroundImages>
```

Then if use:

```
print(bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].background_images[0])
```

I get something very cryptic:

```
<bpy_struct, CameraBackgroundImage at 0x000001B59016BCA8>
```

Is there a more specific attribute that I need to search for?

Also, I am using Blender 2.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the name of a background image with

```
for background_image in bpy.data.cameras['Camera'].background_images:
    print(background_image.image.name)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! And after adding a few more images in my camera, I get a list of camera background image names.